# Will I be able to read this through Ajax (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to call the server AJAX-way, just to get 1 parameter:

Must I do this through JSON?
Or, can I just shoot this through like a regular HTML page, like this:

```
4
```

or

```
6
```

Then, will JavaScript be able to read that line?
If so, how can I do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't have to use JSON, you can return plain text to your AJAX requests if you want.

```
$.get (
    'your_script',
    {
        // parameters
    },
    function ( response ) {
        // whatever you return on the server will be in the response variable
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm currently returning HTML and replacing a div. Very handy :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [jQuery.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "foo.php",
  success: function(msg){
    alert(msg); // alerts 4 or 6
  }
});
```

Comment: IMO, `$.get` should be preferred over `$.ajax` unless you need lower level access to the call. For a simple call like this, `$.get` is a good choice: `$.get("foo.php", function(msg){ alert(msg) });`